# Order by clause when using left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I use `Order by` in SQL queries when I am using left outer join and not all the rows has a value for the column? This is in SQL Server 2005

```
Select * from Order O
left outer join Order_Selection OS on OS.Order_ColorID = O.Order_ColorID    
order by OS.Order_SelectionID asc
```

Not all the rows here have a value for `Order_selectionID`. When I use `DESC`, the order I wanted is messed up and when I use `ASC`, the rows come in the last because the rows without `Order_SelectionID` comes first.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have told us what you don't want but not told us what you do want.

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith -- where do you want those results?  You can use order by ISNULL(OS.Order_SelectionID, 9999) or whatever value you need.

Comment: Oops, did i mess up again! If Order_SelectionID is saved as 101, 102... I want to get the records in the same order 101, 102 and then all other records without Order_SelectioNID. I hope i am clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to avoid relying on `ISNULL(OS.Order_SelectionID, magic_number)`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Order O
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_Selection OS
         ON OS.Order_ColorID = O.Order_ColorID
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN OS.Order_SelectionID IS NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END,
          OS.Order_SelectionID
```

Answer (score -3):

Are the rows with Order_selectionID really necessary? If not use a clause to filter them:

```
and Order_selectionID is not null;
```

or you can substitute the null value for some dummy value, if your data permits that:
in Oracle:

```
select nvl(Order_selectionID, -1) from...
```

Comment: I need those rows with null Order_SelectionID. :-(

Comment: That would effectively turn it back into an `inner join`. `nvl` is not valid TSQL.